# How to use react-bodymovin with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, animation, next.js, bodymovin

react-bodymovin works perfectly for my reactjs app but when being migrated to nextjs, it does not work. I received the following errors:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xyz/work/web/dict/next/node_modules/bodymovin/build/player/bodymovin_light.min.js:1:226)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xyz/work/web/dict/next/node_modules/react-bodymovin/lib/ReactBodymovin.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Justa importing the library bodymovin, it will cause all above

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import SuggestionList from '../components/SuggestionList';
import dict from '../api/dict';
import ReactBodymovin from 'react-bodymovin';
```

If i disable as followings, it works

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Router from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import SuggestionList from '../components/SuggestionList';
import dict from '../api/dict';
//import ReactBodymovin from 'react-bodymovin';
```

Comment: Please put some code or create demo link where we can see exact issue

Comment: @user602874 Please could I be marked as the answer :)

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is most likely due to using an old version of the bodymovin/lottie which does not have the serverside rendering bugfix, thus window is not found as it doesn't exist at serverside compilation time.

Further info here: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ#i-use-a-library-which-throws-window-is-undefined

To solve this:

1) Add the right 3rd party to dependencies: "react-lottie": "^1.2.3"

[Lottie Web](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web) was given [a SSR bugfix](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/440) and [react-lottie](https://github.com/chenqingspring/react-lottie) should be updated to avoid the window issue.

https://github.com/chenqingspring/react-lottie/issues/17

2) Place the following file in ./pages/lottie.js

```
import React from "react";
import Lottie from "react-lottie";
import * as animationData from "../animations/loading-spinner-black.json";

export default class LottieControl extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isStopped: false, isPaused: false };
}

render() {
    const buttonStyle = {
    display: "block",
    margin: "10px auto"
    };

    console.log(animationData);

    const defaultOptions = {
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animationData: animationData.default,
    rendererSettings: {
        preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid slice"
    }
    };

    return (
    <div>
        <Lottie
        options={defaultOptions}
        height={400}
        width={400}
        isStopped={this.state.isStopped}
        isPaused={this.state.isPaused}
        />
        <button
        style={buttonStyle}
        onClick={() => this.setState({ isStopped: true })}
        >
        stop
        </button>
        <button
        style={buttonStyle}
        onClick={() => this.setState({ isStopped: false })}
        >
        play
        </button>
        <button
        style={buttonStyle}
        onClick={() => this.setState({ isPaused: !this.state.isPaused })}
        >
        pause
        </button>
    </div>
    );
}
}
```

3) place the following file in ./animations/loading-spinner-black.json

```
{"v":"5.1.8","fr":29.9700012207031,"ip":0,"op":60.0000024438501,"w":100,"h":100,"nm":"Spinner","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"spinner Outlines","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[50,50,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[160,284,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100,100],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,19.812],[19.882,0],[0,-19.882],[-19.882,0]],"o":[[0,-19.882],[-19.882,0],[0,19.882],[19.882,0]],"v":[[36,0],[0,-36],[-36,0],[0,36]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p667_1_0p167_0p167"],"t":0,"s":[100],"e":[0]},{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0]},"n":["0p833_1_0p167_0"],"t":29,"s":[0],"e":[0]},{"t":51.0000020772726}],"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.333],"y":[0]},"n":["0p833_0p833_0p333_0"],"t":20,"s":[100],"e":[1]},{"t":60.0000024438501}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":2,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0,0,0,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":10,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":10,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[160,284],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.667],"y":[1]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"n":["0p667_1_0p167_0p167"],"t":0,"s":[-90],"e":[270]},{"t":59.0000024031193}],"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 1","np":3,"cix":2,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":60.0000024438501,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
```

4) "npm run dev" and go to http://localhost:3000/lottie and you should see a black spinning animation with controls

Alternatively you can ignore the above if you cannot change your dependencies and force the use of client side code execution via process.cient. See further details [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/2473).

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have further problems, I can make a live example if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked - i was confused between react-lottie and bodymovin which i thought are the same.

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help. Please could you mark this as the answer :)

Comment: even with this react-lottie or lottie-web, i still get the same error.